# Is it possible to send batch of transactions in Ethereum?

Tags: transactions, web3-providers, batch

I wonder whether it is possible to send batch of transactions at once. I am aware that on the contract side this can be done, but this limits the batch execution to a limited number of functions, and even if you make function that makes low level calls to handle any kind of transaction to any other address, there is still problem of being atomic, meaning if one of them fails, all fail, which is something I don't want. All I am asking is to have batch of requests on the first request front, which is when the transaction is first submitted to the network with an asynchronous request.

The submission of that batch transaction request can maybe handled on the provider side. So this way I don't have to send an asynchronous request to the provider for every single transaction, I only send once as a batch, and it submits them to the chain one by one and returns me a result.

Is such thing possible or not, and why? Any idea or information I am not aware in this front is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called flashbot bundles ( https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-auction/searchers/advanced/understanding-bundles) Everything you need should be in these docs. Good luck :)